# Adjusting ActiveX Controls re-Szing and Zorder in VBA when used in a Sheet (not in a Form)

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched extensively and can not find a complete specification for ActiveX Controls/OLE Objects and I'm confused about if they are the same thing or not and how to reference them in VBA.
The material I saw in MSDN is very light and vague and my usual cheat-sheets are silent on this *cough* Chip Pearson *cough*

I have this code in a class module called cChart:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents ch As Chart

Private Sub ch_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal X As Long, _
                         ByVal Y As Long)
    Debug.Print X & Chr(9) & Y
End Sub
```

I have this code in a class module called cTextBox:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents tb As msforms.TextBox
Public cht As Chart
Dim ws As Worksheet

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
End Sub

Private Sub tb_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                         ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    cht.Parent.Activate
'   I want to do this but I cant...
    tb.ZOrder msoSendToBack
'   And I'm forced to do this
    ws.Shapes("TextBox1").ZOrder msoSendToBack
End Sub
Public Sub alignObjects()
    On Error GoTo objectsNotSet
    tb.Top = cht.Top     'at least, I would like to be able to do this line...
objectsNotSet:
    Debug.Print timeStamp(Caller:=cModuleName, Context:=cMyName, message:="ERROR")
End Sub
```

and this in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit
Public chrt As cChart
Public txtB As cTextBox

Sub initChart()
    Set chrt = New cChart
    Set chrt.ch = ActiveChart
End Sub
Sub inittb()
    Set txtB = New cTextBox
    Set txtB.tb = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object
    Set txtB.cht = chrt.ch
End Sub
```

Its just test code and I manually select the Chart before (manually) running initChart and then I manually run inittb.

I would like to get rid of this line

```
ws.Shapes("TextBox1").ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

but there is no name or index property that I can see in the Form.TextBox Object to allow me to do this:

```
ws.Shapes(tb.Name).ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

Do I need to re-cast the Form.TextBox object as a Shape to position and size it and do other useful things like control its Z order and visibility?

And can I not use the Form.XXXX object to get a Name or Index?  Do I really have to hard code these into the shape Object?

If possible, can somebody point me in the general direction of a specification on these objects?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to go back "up" from the TextBox object to its host Shape. You could add a new field in `cTextBox` (`Public shp As Shape`) to hold a reference to the host Shape object: seems it should be uneccessary, but it would at least provide a "clean" workaround.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, thanks. I'll do as you say. I think the key phrase from your comment is "Host Shape"... Much better paradigm than my original "vagrant textbox" approach.